# How to mock up one method in a module other than mock up the whole module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-mock

My purpose is to mock up the return value of `utcnow`. I am using `pytest` and pretty new on it.

The method in `my_file.py` and under module `my_module`:

```
import datetime

def get_date_info() -> Tuple[int, str]:
    now_epoch = int(datetime.utcnow().strftime("%s"))
    # do something with now_epoch
    calculated_epoch = ...

    # another variable relies on datetime
    another_variable = datetime.fromtimestamp(calculated_epoch).strftime("%H")
return (now_epoch, another_variable)
```

My `pytest` test for the method:

```
from my_module.my_file import get_date_info
import datetime
import mock

@mock.patch("my_module.my_file.datetime")
def test_get_date_info():
        mock_dt.utcnow = mock.Mock(return_value=datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 1))
        actual_epoch, actual_another_variable = get_date_info()
        # assert code here
```

The returned `actual_epoch` is accurate with the mocked date, unfortunately the below code didn't return str but  `<MagicMock name='datetime.fromtimestamp().strftime()' id='140249763149088'>`

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(calculated_epoch).strftime("%H")
```

Does anyone know what causes the issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are mocking only `utcnow`, so when utcnow is invoked in the actual code - it returns your mocked value. You have to mock `datetime.fromtimestamp` as well for it to return your mocked value.
eg:

```
mock_dt.fromtimestamp = mock.Mock(return_value=datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks Felix. I figured out as well.